# Digital goods' seller-word suggestions

Tags: word-choice

We are creating an online marketplace, so we need some word suggestions.

1. Someone who sells the goods online.
2. Someone who buys the goods online.

Given that we already know seller, vendor, customer etc. words; we would like to choose something more creative.

Answer (score 1):

A business that sells online is often called an **[etailer](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/etailer)**

> an internet retailer

While less common, the term **[ebuyer](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=eBuyer)** is sometimes used

> Slang word for an e-commerce buyer. Typically found in feedback comments on sites such as eBay.

The latter term is also a trademark of a computer seller in UK

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use different words for an online seller.  It is just a seller who sells to a customer.  In today's world using tech jargon for seller/vendor/customer makes it seem like you are behind the times.

Answer (score 0):

purveyor
acquirer
would be more fancy

shoppers paradise

sellers nirvana

digi-merchant

e-trader well e-trade already exists

e-sellerate? already exists

sellomax ? esellomax?

what's my commission by the way?

Comment: Thanks for words, I am checking their meaning and popularities. Your commision: 1000%

Answer (score 0):

someone who buys a good can be vendee.
someone who sells a good can be vendor or merchant.